# Function inside useEffect fire twice even with empty dependency array

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have this example from https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-firebase-authentication/utils/auth/useUser.js

The effect works fine (fires once) but for some reason, the functions inside are called twice.

```
    useEffect(() => {
    
    const cancelAuthListener = firebase
      .auth()
      .onIdTokenChanged(async (user) => {
        console.log('once or twice?')
        if (user) {
    
          // This fires twice

          const userData = await mapUserData(user)
          setUserCookie(userData)
          setUser(userData)
        } else {
          removeUserCookie()
          setUser()
        }
      })

    const userFromCookie = getUserFromCookie()
    if (!userFromCookie) {
      router.push('/')
      return
    }
    setUser(userFromCookie)
    console.log(' i fire once')
    return () => {
      console.log('clean up')
      cancelAuthListener()
    }
    
  }, [])
```

How can I make it to fire once?
I added some console logs:
On the first render I get: 'i fire once', 'once or twice', 'once or twice'
If I leave the page the cleanup console log fires (as it's supposed to do)
Many thanks

Later edit:
this is the code

```
export const mapUserData = async (user) => {
  const { uid, email } = user
  const token = await user.getIdToken()
  
  return {
    id: uid,
    email,
    token
  }
}
```

If getIdToken() gets 'true' as an argument it will force a refresh regardless of token expiration.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#getidtoken

Comment: The code you posted seems correct, but how about the parent component?  and the [] effect runs twice, when it mounts and when unmounts ;), maybe what's happening is that when the component mounts it's called, and when the component unmounts.

Comment: I am not sure but check `what user coming` in both logs. Code seems ok to me

Comment: Seems like a good solution but not tried it yet. Im converting to Typescript.

Answer (score 1):

Solved!!
the user was calling getIdToken(true) which forces a refresh.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#getidtoken

Sorry guys, my bad!!!

Comment: Done, I made an edit to the original post

Answer (score -2):

You have a setState() inside useEffect thats the culprit, where useEffect having empty params [], one request on initial mount and another when do
setUser(userData) the component re-renders and useEffect() is invoked again.

Instead of using user as state, try using as ref and check. That might resolve this.

Comment: the effect runs fine. setState does not trigger another fire as it's not in the dependency array

Comment: Have you checked removing the setUser(userData)